# Sails.js where to store security credentials?

Tags: sails.js, configuration-files

I store the username and password for a database connection in

```
/config/connections.js
```

Where would I store something more general like AWS credentials?

I imagine saving an object like below in some file.

```
module.exports.aws = {
 key:'my key',
 secret: 'my token',
 bucket: 'my bucket'
}
```

and then using it like this:

```
req.file('image')
  .upload({
    adapter:require('skipper-s3'),
    key:aws.key,
    secret:aws.secret,
    bucket:aws.bucket,
  }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Never store credentials in source code. Use environment variables:

```
{
  secret: process.env.MY_SECRET
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you look in AWS EB, this is how AWS tell you to do this as well. However, some systems limit how many env variables you can use.

Comment: what is the reasoning behind that? If I have a script that sets the environment variables in production before running sails does that count as "in source code"?

Comment: If its in source control, it's source code. This is not sailsjs-specific by the way, it's generally accepted best practices.

Comment: I love how I just got downvoted for describing the best practice for securely managing credentials in node.js source code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the npm package [nconf](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf) Its great because it lets you define a file to load configuration from when doing local testing, but for production it can load configuration from environmental variables without any code changes.